# Why did Rand destroy this item? Spoilers KoD

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

> The Choedan Kal are two giant sa'angreal that were created during the War of Power, one for a man and one for a woman. They are the two most powerful sa'angreal ever created.

Rand was successful in cleansing the taint from saidin, but in the attempt, the female access key was destroyed as well as the sa'angreal itself. The male counterpart remained in Rand's possession.

However, later he draws in as much power as he can through the sa'angreal and drives it back through itself, purposely obliterating it.

The Sa'angreal especially the CK which were the most powerful ever made would have made last battle much easier. Rand could've used it to destroy the numerous shadow spawn with it. It was more powerful than Callandor without the flaw.

Why is it that then Rand intentionally destroyed it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IIRC there is a passage where Rand says something like he cant risk the key falling into the hands of the forsaken however if I am remembering incorrectly this reasoning would still make sense the risk of an enemy obtaining the key would far outweigh the benefits of keeping it.

It is also possible Rand couldnt trust anyone even himself (since he did worry that he was already insane) with that kind of power, with just a single object even the weakest channeler could have broken the world all over again.

Comment: I am not sure security would have been an issue. He had kept the access keys hidden for a long time after he fought Asmodean. Unless the only benefit he wanted was that of cleansing saidin. Rand could'nt trust himself is another thing because of the voice of LTT.

Comment: @Arcane Just remember when Rand destroyed the key. He was at the edge of giving up everthing on the top of Dragon Mountain, after a failure attemp of destroying all the Seanchan